# Callable function has wrong url

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So when I create a Firebase cloud function like this:

```
exports.create_event = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https
  .onCall((data, context) => {
    ... here goes my Promise ...
  });
}
```

Then I initialize my firebase stuff inside of App.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  appID: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And then call it from my client app, from another class:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/functions";

firebase
  .app()
  .functions("europe-west1")
  .httpsCallable("create_event")(somevalues)
  .then(() => {
    ...
   })
   .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I can see that it's pointing to a wrong URL when I execute code in browser. Instead of calling the url *europe-west-myappid.cloudfunctions...*, it actually calls following URL:

```
https://europe-west1-undefined.cloudfunctions.net/create_event
```

Instead of **undefined**, it should specify my app ID, or whatever it is. Am I doing a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after long hours of figuring this out, I realized that I havent created **an app in Firebase console**. Apparently, when you create a project, it's not yet finished - you got to create app as well, otherwise the same issue will happen to you.